# Crash - Sending non-protected broadcast

Tags: android

I've searched this log but everything I've seen just says it's a warning.  For some background, this does NOT crash on Oreo, but it DOES crash on Pie.  I have no idea what broadcast could be causing it.

I've put breakpoints at every place I call "sendBroadcast" and can confirm that the crash happens before any broadcast is sent from the app.

if you require any code from any class, let me know and I'll put it up immediately

Any idea why this would be crashing on Pie?

```
2019-01-03 09:18:09.043 879-1094/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1023 com.android.server.am.AppStateBroadcaster.broadcastAppState:125 com.android.server.am.AppStateBroadcaster.sendApplicationFocusGain:49 com.android.server.am.OnePlusAmUtil$OnePlusActivityManagerService$1.run:346 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:873 
2019-01-03 09:18:09.043 879-6821/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 (pid 31022) has died: fore SVC 
2019-01-03 09:18:09.043 1959-1959/? D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
2019-01-03 09:18:09.043 1801-1801/? I/Zygote: Process 31022 exited cleanly (0)
2019-01-03 09:18:09.046 1959-1959/? I/QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=4446 length=24
2019-01-03 09:18:09.047 879-1094/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast diagandroid.app.ApplicationState from system 879:system/1000 pkg android
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:23205)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:23790)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:24025)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1029)
        at com.android.server.am.AppStateBroadcaster.broadcastAppState(AppStateBroadcaster.java:125)
        at com.android.server.am.AppStateBroadcaster.sendApplicationFocusGain(AppStateBroadcaster.java:49)
        at com.android.server.am.OnePlusAmUtil$OnePlusActivityManagerService$1.run(OnePlusAmUtil.java:346)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

Comment: Look in your logs for "FATAL" instead, as this may just be a red herring. If your application is actually crashing, you should get a stack trace.

Comment: you were right!  in 300 lines there's 1 reference to fatal:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;  A search on stackoverflow gives me the answer to that.  Thank you so much.  Put this as an answer so I can give you a check mark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Occasionally you'll see stack traces printed in Logcat that are unrelated to your application. To find out what specifically is causing your crash, do a search for the word "FATAL". This will typically lead you to the actual cause of your application crash.

Comment: Thank you this helped me pin point my issues, this was driving me nuts hahaha